# ValidationError when modifying an object with inline admin

Tags: django, admin

I've got a `Position` model with a ForeignKey field related to an `Emplacement` model.
In the admin of `Emplacement` I set an Inline admin for `Position`.

What I want to achieve is that when the `num_position` field is modified in a `Emplacement` instance, the positions related to this instance are deleted and new ones are created.

To achieve this I override the `Emplacement` model's `save()` method and check whether `num_position` has changed.

The problem is that when saving an `Emplacement` model after modification of its `num_position` field, I get the following error:

```
ValidationError: Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.
```

I guess it has to do with the deletion/recreation of the positions, but I can't find why.

What's wrong?

**models.py**

```
class Emplacement(models.Model): 

    num_position = models.IntegerField()
    # more fields

    __original_num_position = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Emplacement, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__original_num_position = self.num_position

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if self.num_position != self._Emplacement__original_num_position:
            # if num_position has changed, delete existing positions and recreate <num_position> positions
            Position.objects.filter(emplacement=self).delete()            
            for i in range(self.num_position):
                position = Position()
                position.emplacement = self
                position.number = i+1
                position.save()

        super(Emplacement, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Position(models.Model):
    emplacement = models.ForeignKey(Emplacement)
    number = models.IntegerField()
```

**admin.py**

```
class PositionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Position

class EmplacementAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PositionInline]

my_site.register(Emplacement, EmplacementAdmin)
```

**EDIT**

I also tried with a signal, but got the same error:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Emplacement)
def create_positions(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """Create positions when num_position has changed."""
    if instance.num_position != instance.old_num_position:
        Position.objects.filter(emplacement=instance).delete()
        for i in range(instance.num_position):
            position = Position()
            position.emplacement = instance
            position.numero = i+1            
            position.save()
```

Comment: I just tried creating a new django project and pasting this code in an app.  I don't see any errors when I create/save Emplacement/Position objects.  Do you see the exception when running just this code, or is there some specific way to trigger the error?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered exactly the same issue.
Finally solved it by not implementing the create/delete logic on the Model-side but in the Forms/FormSets.

So in the 'main' admin class, in your case 'EmplacementAdmin', extended the save_formset method:

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    instance = form.instance
    deleted = []
    if instance and instance.__original_num_position != instance.num_position:
        ''' create new Positions if needed '''

        formset.delete_positions = None # pass on a list, QuerySet, whatever

    super(EmplacementAdmin, self).save_formset(request, form, formset, change)
```

And create a PositionFormSet like so:

```
class PositionFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    delete_positions = []

    @property
    def deleted_forms(self):
        deleted_forms = []
        try:
            deleted_forms = super(PositionFormSet, self).deleted_forms
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        for form in self.forms:
            if form.instance in self.delete_positions:
                 deleted_forms.append(form)
        self.delete_positions = []
        return deleted_forms
```

And set this formset in your inlineadmin:

```
class PositionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Position
    formset = PositionFormSet
```

Not exactly the way I had in mind, but the trick worked for me. Curious to know if there are some more elegant solutions :-)